# Nginx + alias + php == 404 file not found

Tags: php, nginx

I have a default nginx + php installation on Ubuntu 20.04.

I want to map each users `~/public_html` to example.com/user.
For that i use the following

```
location ~ ^/(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
    alias /home/$1/public_html$2;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    autoindex on;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

And it *almost* works. It serves static files just fine, but for php files I always get a `404 File not Found`.

example.com/user/  **Works** (directory index)

example.com/user/test.html **Works** (static html file)

example.com/user/test.php **Gives 404** (php file)

There are loads of similar questions out there and it feels like I have tried all the solutions but none seems to work.

Comment: I think you should place the second location block outside of the first one, also place the index index.html rules at the top (outside the location block, but within the server block)

Comment: Apparently ALL other posts on SO says to have a php location block inside of the alias location block. Thats why I am going this way. 

I did try without but to no better results.

Comment: Try using named captures for the `alias` statement. For example: `location ~ ^/(?<user>.+?)(?<path>/.*)?$ { alias /home/$user/public_html$path; ...`

Comment: Thanks. That atleast made it easier to debug. 

But it still tries to get the files from the wrong path.

`2020/08/27 09:56:00 [debug] 30181#30181: *1 trying to use file: "/10los01/katt.php" "/home/10los01/public_html/katt.php/10los01/katt.php"`